# data in component is not updating react native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, checkbox, render, flatlist

I'm creating a taxes app, and I'm having trouble with the components in React Native. When I receive a collection from the backend and show that data in two flat lists, the first one works fine and shows the year and the amount to pay. However, the second one, which lists each installment for that particular year, allows the user to check or uncheck the installment to pay. When I check the installments, it works, but when I uncheck them, it doesn't update the new array of installments. i dont know what im doing wrong, this is my code so far

YEARS COMPONENT

```
  const MemorizedFlatList = memo(FlatList);
// prevent this component from re-rendering

export const RowAnios = memo(({item}:Props) => {
     const [show, setShow] = useState({
        anio:'',
        mostrar:false
     });
     const [cuota, setCuotas] = useState<Cuota[] | []>([]);

     // calculates total debt
     const total = item.reduce((acc,curr)=> acc + curr.totalcuota,0);
     const recargo = item.reduce((acc,curr)=> acc + curr.totalcuota + curr.recargo,0);

     //checks if cuota changed
     useEffect(() => {
        console.log('ROW ANIOS',cuota)
     }, [cuota]);

     //checks if show changed and modifies item.checked
     const handleShow = async () =>{
       if(cuota.length){
       await updateList(item, cuota);
       
        setShow({
        anio:item[0].anio,
        mostrar:!show.mostrar 
        });
       }
        setShow({
            anio:item[0].anio,
            mostrar:!show.mostrar 
        })
     }

     const updateList = (list:any, accountNumbers:any) => {
        console.log('UPDATE LIST')
        return new Promise(resolve => {
          const updatedList = list.map((item : any) => {
            if (accountNumbers.includes(item.cuota)) {
              return item.checked = true
            } else {
              return item.checked = false;
            }
          });
          resolve(updatedList);
        });
      };
      
  return (
    <>
        <Box mt={2} display={'flex'} flexDirection={'row'} alignItems={'center'} justifyContent={'space-around'}>
            <Box width={'15%'} display={'flex'} flexDirection={'row'} alignItems={'center'} justifyContent={'space-between'}>
                <Pressable onPress={() => handleShow()} width={'100%'} flexDirection={'row'}>
                    <Icon name={'chevron-right'} size={15} color={'cyan'}/>
                    <Text textAlign={'center'} fontSize={'sm'}>
                        {item[0].anio}
                    </Text>
                </Pressable>
            </Box>
            <Box width={'29%'}  display={'flex'}  alignItems={'center'}>
                <Text textAlign={'center'} fontSize={'sm'} >
                {total.toFixed(2)}
                </Text>
            </Box>
            <Box width={'29%'} display={'flex'} alignItems={'center'} >
                <Text textAlign={'center'} fontSize={'sm'} fontWeight={'bold'}>
                {recargo.toFixed(2) }
                </Text>
            </Box>
            <Box width={'27%'} display={'flex'}  alignItems={'center'}>
                <Text textAlign={'center'} fontSize={'sm'} >
                {total.toFixed(2)}
                </Text>
            </Box>
        </Box>
        <Divider mt={1}/>
        { show.anio === item[0].anio && show.mostrar ?
                <Animatable.View animation='fadeInDown' style={{backgroundColor:'white'}}>
                        <Box  mt={2} alignSelf={'center'} width={'95%'} display={'flex'} flexDirection={'row'} alignItems={'center'} justifyContent={'space-around'}>
                <Text width={'32%'}fontSize={'sm'} color={'#2596be'} textAlign={'center'} fontWeight={'bold'}>
                    CUOTA
                </Text>
                <Text width={'32%'} fontSize={'sm'} color={'#2596be'} textAlign={'center'} fontWeight={'bold'} lineHeight={'sm'}>
                    VENCIMIENTO
                </Text>
                
                <Text width={'24%'} fontSize={'sm'} color={'#2596be'} textAlign={'center'} fontWeight={'bold'} lineHeight={'sm'}>
                    TOTAL
                </Text>
                </Box>
              
                    <ScrollView 
                    scrollEnabled={true}
                    nestedScrollEnabled={true}
                    keyboardShouldPersistTaps='always'
                    height={'40'}
                    >
                        <MemorizedFlatList
                            data={item}
                            keyExtractor={(item: any, index:any) => item.cunica + index.toString()}
                            renderItem={({item}) => <RowListaCuotas item={item} cuotas={cuota} setCuotas={setCuotas}/>}
                            nestedScrollEnabled={true}
                        />
                    </ScrollView>
            
                    <Box mt={2} bg={'gray.300'} flexDirection={'row'} justifyContent={'flex-end'}>
                        <Text  fontSize={'sm'} fontWeight={'bold'}>
                            TOTAL A PAGAR
                        </Text>
                        <Text width={"27%"} textAlign={'center'}  fontSize={'sm'} fontWeight={'bold'}>
                            $10.000
                        </Text>
                    </Box>
                </Animatable.View>
        : null}
    </>  
  )
})
```

INSTALLMENTS FLATLIST

```
    import { Box, Checkbox, Text,  } from 'native-base'
import React,{useContext, useEffect, useState, memo} from 'react'
//@ts-ignore
import { Cuota } from '../../interfaces/inmuebles/deuda';
import { DatosContext } from '../context/datos/DatosContext';

interface Props {
    item: any,
    cuotas: Cuota[] | [],
    setCuotas: React.Dispatch<React.SetStateAction<[] | Cuota[]>>
}

export const RowListaCuotas = memo(({item,cuotas ,setCuotas}:Props) => {
    let {numeroCuota} = useContext(DatosContext);

    useEffect(() => {
       // numeroCuota = cuotas;
    }, [cuotas]); 

    const ordenarFecha = (fecha:string) => {
        if(fecha){
            const fechaArray = fecha.split('-');
        const dia = fechaArray[2].split('T')[0];
        return `${dia}/${fechaArray[1]}/${fechaArray[0]}`
        }
        return 'Sin fecha';   
    }

     const handleCheck = (value:boolean) => {
      if(value){
        const cuotaExistente = numeroCuota.find((cuota:Cuota) => cuota === item.cuota)
        if(cuotaExistente) return;
        numeroCuota.push(item.cuota as never)
          setCuotas([...numeroCuota])
       }else{
        console.log('CUOTAS BEFORE UNCHECK',numeroCuota)
            const newCuotas = numeroCuota.filter((cuota:Cuota) => {
                return cuota !== item.cuota
            })
           setCuotas([...newCuotas])
    }
}

  return (
    <Box alignSelf={'center'} width={'95%'} mt={2} display={'flex'} flexDirection={'row'} justifyContent={'space-around'} alignItems={'center'}>
        <Box width={'32%'} display={'flex'} flexDirection={'row'} alignItems={'center'} justifyContent={'space-around'}>
                    <Checkbox value='nuevo' defaultIsChecked={item.checked} onChange={ handleCheck } accessibilityLabel='algo'/>
                    <Text textAlign={'center'} fontSize={'sm'}>
                        {ordenarFecha(item.fecha_pago)}
                    </Text>
            </Box>
            <Box width={'28%'} display={'flex'} alignItems={'center'}>
                <Text textAlign={'center'} fontSize={'sm'} >
                    {ordenarFecha(item.fecha_ven1)}
                </Text>
            </Box>
            
            <Box  width={'24%'} display={'flex'}  alignItems={'center'}>
                <Text textAlign={'center'} fontSize={'sm'} >
                    {item.totalcuota.toFixed(2)}
                </Text>
            </Box>
        </Box>
  )
})
```

these are my logs, as you can see when i check an item it is pushed to the array and stores the new value in the component row anios, but when i uncheck the item the array does not updates
[image: console log]